# Xamarin.Forms: Looking code sample for receive and send push notification with Amazon Simple Notification Service

Tags: amazon-s3, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, amazon-sns

I have gone through the links below as I spent most of the time implementing the code and configuration related to push notification with Amazon SNS in Xamarin.Forms, but I am unable to achieve it.

Please help. Thanks.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/getting-started-sns-android.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/getting-started-sns-ios.html

Comment: What does “unable to complete them” mean?  If you actually include details about the problems  you’re having we could help you

Comment: @Jason, I mean to say that unable to achieve to use Amazon SNS feature in Xamarin cross platform.

Comment: What are permissions required to enable Push notification in android manifest. Those things are missing in Amazon SNS documentation. Please check once the official link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/getting-started-sns-android.html